# Integrate social networks api in android

Tags: android

I want to integrate multiple social networks in my android project so that when i want to post or share images and videos i can just do it with one click and it is shared on my all social networking accounts all together.

Comment: if anybody has any idea please help!!! i have tried many api's but they have some or other error. i am new to android so please tell all the steps. its urgent!!!

Comment: check http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent/

Comment: Every social networking sites have their own SDKs. Download them,import them and start working.

Comment: downloading each sdk and using gives error. I want to build something like polarbear or hootsuite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all social networks, try this library.

[socialauth](https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/)

Comment: i tried socialauth but its some classes are missing for eg: custom adapter. if you have full code of socialauth please do send it

Comment: i searched the complete code for socialauth api and implemented it but customui wasn't working at all and in sharebutton update button din't work. please help!!

Comment: can you tell me any android api which collects data from all social networking websites using a search box defined by user.

Comment: Sorry but there is no such built in API by Android.  You have to proceed with 3rd party solution like SocialAuth.

Comment: socialauth is for posting not collecting data from social networking sites. how can it help?

Comment: if that is collecting data, you may need to implement all native sdks , but keep searching for alternative :)

Comment: please tell me any android api on How to search specific HashTags in all social networking sites

Comment: Dude i am afraid that there are not such APIs.  You have to manually add all the SDKs and try.

Comment: ok please guide me for it i am new to android.

Comment: just google, there are plenty examples and official docs

Comment: ok thanx for help i'll do that right away